# What's the difference between difficulty levels in Maze Invaders?

Tags: atari-50-anniversary-celebration, maze-invaders

The Dip Switch Settings for Maze Invaders in *Atari 50: The Anniversary Celebration* has 4 difficulty levels: Easier, Easy, Hard, and Harder. What is the difference between these difficulty levels?

[image: Dip Switch Settings]